# Django REST framework API occurs ConnectionDoesNotExist

Tags: django, reactjs, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am learning the decoupled Django with Django-rest-framework and React for web development. The database is PostgreSQL.

I have configured API, and when I run http://127.0.0.1:8000/api, it looks fine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7hmp.png)

But if I click the link in this API(http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todos/), it fails:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yct4K.png)

I can't figure out what is going on.

my backend/urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers

from todos import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'todos', views.TodoView,'todo')

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^', include('todos.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

my backend/settings.py is:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'igphn#&4b(67(*=!u)lr1wr=jtfhvgwc03nl&5+t7m18%-#ttm'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'todos',
    'corsheaders',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'todos',
        'USER': 'luyaoye',
        'PASSWORD': '1234567',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432'
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# whitelist localhost:3000 where frontend will be served
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('localhost:3000/')

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20
}
```

my todos/serializers.py is:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Todos

class TodoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Todos
        fields=['id','title','notes','created_at','completed',]
```

my todos/views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import TodoSerializer 
from .models import Todos

class TodoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer         
    queryset = Todos.objects.using('todos').all()
```

my todos/models.py is:

```
from django.db import models

class Todos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        # display todos brief
        return self.title
```

My PostgreSQL database is running locally as well, and having data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1ntN.png)

Anyone can help??

Comment: Where do you have your Rest endpoints? You should have `/api/todos` somewhere in your pythin code.  Use postman app in order to test your Rest endpoints prior testing with frontend. Also look for traversymedia channel on youtube because he has a python video explaining Rest endpounts. Cheers!

Comment: the `/api/todos` isn't handled by `router.register(r'todos', views.TodoView,'todo')`? I was following a tutorial that did so. But anyway, I rewrite the REST endpoint by moving the router part to `todos/urls.py`, and add `urlpatterns = router.urls`, lastly, I repalced `url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))` with `url(r'^api/', include('todos.urls')` in the `backend/urls.py`, then problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

In queryset property of your **TodoView**, you don't have to write `using('todos')` part.

`using()` is meant for applications with multiple databases and tells django to use different DB connection (it uses `DATABASES['default']` by default).
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database-for-a-queryset

So if you remove using part - everything should be working.